# Strange jQuery AJAX success function behaviour

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP contact form that I'm using with jQuery's AJAX method, but I'm getting very strange results with the "success:" function.

Here's the PHP contact form:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$msg = "Name: $name\n";
$msg .= "Email: $email\n";
$msg .= "Number: $number\n\n";
$msg .= "$message\n";
$recipient = "[recipients here]";
$subject = "Contact Us - $name";
$mailheaders = "From:$email";
$success = mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);

if ($success) {
    echo ('Correct');
} else {
    echo ('Failed');
}
header("Location: [website address here]");
?>
```

Here's the jQuery AJAX method:

```
$("#contact-form").submit(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/lib/mailer.php',
        data: {
            name: $("#name").val(),
            email: $("#email").val(),
            number: $("#number").val(),
            message: $("#message").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //$("#contact-form")[0].reset();
            alert(data);

            if(data === 'Correct') {
                alert('Data is correct');
            }
            else if (data !== 'Correct') {
                alert('Data is not equal to correct');
            }
            else {
                alert('Else statement');
            }
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Now, when I fill in the form and click submit, the PHP receives the right data and successfully sends the email, and echo's "Correct". An alert pops up saying "Correct". But then, instead of the next alert being "Data is correct", it is "Data is not equal to correct".

I have no idea what's going on here for that to happen. I'm assuming I must be making a really stupid mistake somewhere but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: remove header("Location: [website address here]");

Comment: check the string length of data received in your javascript function. May be space is present at the end of string.

Comment: Remove the header part and code it like below answer..

Comment: Is this the code as you are using it? I ask as it seems using AJAX in this instance doesn't provide any benefits - you are not presenting any error messages to the user, validating input, or the like. You may as well as the form submit to whatever page you redirect them to on success and have all the processing performed there.

Comment: Put `async:false` in the ajax function. Also remove the `header` from the php page

Comment: Shehzad Bilal, you are correct. For some reason there's a trailing space after the word "Correct", which is causing this issue. Any idea why a space is being added at the end of the echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not matching the word.
Use

```
if($.trim(data) == 'Correct')
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. For some reason, there was a space after "Correct" which was causing this issue. No idea why the PHP response is adding a trailing space though...

Comment: Mention not. Yes most of the time it happens. So usually send response with json_encode and then parse it in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can not redirect from `ajax` call. If you are using `header` function it will print many header data in ajax success.

Header data is the `Strange Result` you are getting ...

remove `header("Location: [website address here]");`

And if you want to redirect after success, do it like this in `ajax success` block

```
if (data == "Correct") {
    window.location = '[website addresss here]';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the header location being set was supposed to be removed already, but I've deleted it now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `header("Location: [website address here]")` from your `mailer.php` page

And

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/lib/mailer.php',
        data: {
            name: $("#name").val(),
            email: $("#email").val(),
            number: $("#number").val(),
            message: $("#message").val()
        },
        async:false, //  <---- Add this fella here
        success: function (data) {
            //$("#contact-form")[0].reset();
            alert(data);

            if(data === 'Correct') {
                alert('Data is correct');
            }
            else if (data != 'Correct') {
                alert('Data is not equal to correct');
            }
            else {
                alert('Else statement');
            }
        }
    });
```